# Git commit problem: Unable to append to .git/

Tags: git, permissions, github

I am unable to commit changes in my project when using git.

Here is my terminal:

```
tomas@tomas-laptop:~/menu_operations$ git commit -m "initial commit"
error: Unable to append to .git/logs/refs/heads/7.x-1.x: Permission denied
fatal: cannot update HEAD ref
```

`menu_operations` is the name of my project.

I don't know what permission I have to allow.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> Check the user and permission on .git/logs/refs/heads/, maybe you ran something as root.

Explanation: when you run some git commands as root (sudo?) any new files/directories created will be owned by root, and by default[1] other users won't have write permission on these files/directories.

When you, later, work with that repository, things may *appear* to work, until the time that you need to *write to* a file that was in fact created by root, i.e. *owned by* root.

This should fix it, at least on linux:

```
 sudo chown -Rc $UID .git/
```

It will also show you any files that it changed owners for.

[1]in a sane setup, at least

Comment: thank you both. You were right. The command sudo chown did help and now it is ok. Tomas Teicher

Comment: For Mac users: `sudo chown -R $UID .git/`.

Comment: @manakor but then it doesn't "also show you any files that it changed owners for", of course. You could probably get that with `find . -not -uid $UID -ls -exec chown $UID {} +`.

Comment: Thanks it works for me, but I had to change `$UID` with value returned by `id -u *your_username*`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user and permission on .git/logs/refs/heads/, maybe you ran something as root.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add for those deploying with Capistrano that you should be working with the .git/ directories here

```
/var/www/rails/production/shared/git_cache/.git
```

and

```
/var/www/rails/production/current/.git
```

This assumes you're using these given directories and that you're pushing to production... but it should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Linux command:

- sudo chown -Rc $UID .git/
- id -u {yourusername}

and the outcome:
changed ownership of ‘.git/packed-refs’ from root to 1000

changed ownership of ‘.git/logs/HEAD’ from root to 1000

changed ownership of ‘.git/logs/refs/heads/master’ from root to 1000

changed ownership of ‘.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD’ from root to 1000

changed ownership of ‘.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master’ from root to 1000

changed ownership of ‘.git/objects/pack/pack-b905d78889aea64ca69a61c0efaa76ba95b08786.idx’ from root to 1000

changed ownership of ‘.git/objects/pack/pack-b905d78889aea64ca69a61c0efaa76ba95b08786.pack’ from root to 1000

changed ownership of ‘.git/objects/info/packs’ from root to 1000

changed ownership of ‘.git/info/refs’ from root to 1000

Answer (score 0):

use

sudo chown -R youremailid .git/

Answer (score -1):

chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local.git should do it.